# mysql distinct statement not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
  $query = "SELECT DISTINCT t.task_id, e.url,e.error_id, p.page_rank, e.scan_status, e.url_is_route,e.url_is_route,e.forbidden_word,e.google_host_fail,e.google_cache_fail,e.google_title_fail,e.robots_noindex_nofollow,e.xrobots_noindex_nofollow,e.title_fetch_warn,e.h1_fail,e.h2_fail,e.h3_fail,e.h1_warn,e.h2_warn,e.h3_warn 
              FROM `error_report` AS e 
              INNER JOIN task_pages AS t ON t.task_id=e.task_id
              INNER JOIN `pages` AS p ON p.page_id=t.page_id
              WHERE t.task_id=" . $this->task_id ;
```

I want the query to be distinct only by t.task_id. The problem is that when I add more fields..the query isnt distinct anymore. Is there still a way to select distinct by t.task_id only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `distinct` use `group by`

```
$query = "SELECT t.task_id, e.url,e.error_id, p.page_rank, e.scan_status, e.url_is_route,e.url_is_route,e.forbidden_word,e.google_host_fail,e.google_cache_fail,e.google_title_fail,e.robots_noindex_nofollow,e.xrobots_noindex_nofollow,e.title_fetch_warn,e.h1_fail,e.h2_fail,e.h3_fail,e.h1_warn,e.h2_warn,e.h3_warn 
          FROM `error_report` AS e 
          INNER JOIN task_pages AS t ON t.task_id=e.task_id
          INNER JOIN `pages` AS p ON p.page_id=t.page_id
          WHERE t.task_id=" . $this->task_id
          ."group by t.task_id";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add more fields, you should use `GROUP BY` iirc.

Note that your extra fields *should* be aggregates, e.g. `MIN`, `MAX`, etc. MySQL is more forgiving and shows the first value of each field (though not reliably apparently).

Comment: but I have no use for min, max...etc

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd That's fine, but your query is basically not portable to any other database engine ;-)